# How to remove first item from list javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a to-do list and i need to know how to remove the first
item from a ordered list.
How do i do this? Here s some of my code...

```
   <ul id="todo-list">

   <li>Walk dog</li>

   <li>Buy eggs</li>

   <li>Go for a Walk</li>

  </ul>

<button onclick="removeTask()">Remove first task</button>

function removeTask(){

//what do i put here to remove first item
//from list (walk dog)?

}
```

I need the list with the first item removed when you click the button.

Please Help
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```js
  const list = document.getElementById('todo-list');   

function removeTask(){

   list.querySelector('li').remove()
}
```

```html
  <ul id="todo-list">

   <li>Walk dog</li>

   <li>Buy eggs</li>

   <li>Go for a Walk</li>

  </ul>

<button onclick="removeTask()">Remove first task</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelector` to get the first child, and `removeChild` to remove it:

```js
const list = document.getElementById("todo-list");

function removeTask() {
  list.removeChild(list.querySelector("li"));
}
```

```html
<ul id="todo-list">

  <li>Walk dog</li>

  <li>Buy eggs</li>

  <li>Go for a Walk</li>

</ul>

<button onclick="removeTask()">Remove first task</button>
```